# RESTful Service Put Request

Tags: c#, mongodb, rest

I am implementing a RESTful service in c# 4.0 that will persist to mongoDB. I am new to this and I am trying to implement a PUT method:

```
public void EditFoo(Foo updatedFoo)
```

and another method that updates something in a sublist of object Foo

```
public void EditFooSublistObj(string fooId, SublistObj updatedSublistObj)
```

I have looked through other code and it seems split between reassigning the previous object and updating each of the fields individually without any logic to check the fields.

eg. case 1:

```
prevFoo = updatedFoo;
```

case 2:

```
prevFoo.bar = updatedFoo.bar;
prevFoo.blat = updatedFoo.blat;
... for all fields
```

Does it make any difference? What is a better practice?

Comment: Preference: do less work, whatever is easier to maintain, performs well, and is **valid** for your scenario. :)

Comment: @WiredPrairie As a corollary question is it bad form to use an AddFoo and DeleteFoo Method that you have already implemented to achieve the edit purpose?

Comment: Bad form? It's unusual, and you could end up using unnecessary disk space if MongoDB doesn't reuse the same space on disk as the document was previously stored.